# How to configure Highcharts so that it displays some pre-defined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have been searching and struggling to find a solution for my problem for a long time but no luck.

I have a simple screen where i ask user to enter their score. Once they enter their score my graph shows up with my pre-defined average score and highest score. In this case, my average score is 1450 and the highest score is 1900.

What i want to do is that once my page is loaded i want my graph displays the average and highest score already. Once user enter his score then it shows up.

Below is my code and you can see it here: [**http://jsfiddle.net/8jomr1wd/**](http://jsfiddle.net/8jomr1wd/)

Any idea?

```
        $(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            var val1,
            options;
            val1 = parseFloat($('input[name=entered]').val());
            if ((val1 >= 0) && (val1 <= 1900)) {
                // start creating the chart
                options = {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Title'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'This is subtitle'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category',
                        labels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        legend: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        categories: ['Your score', 'Average', 'Highest Score']
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            borderColor: '#000000',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            colorByPoint: true
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        max: 1900,
                        tickInterval: 100,
                        title: 'test'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Score',
                        data: [val1, 1450, 1900]
                    }],
                };
            } else {
                $("#result").append("<div>Score must be between 0-1900</div>");
            }
            $('#container').highcharts(options);
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    create(0)
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var val1,
        options;
        val1 = parseFloat($('input[name=entered]').val());
        create(val1);
    });
});
});
function create(val1){
        if ((val1 >= 0) && (val1 <= 1900)) {
            // start creating the chart
            options = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Title'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'This is subtitle'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    labels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    categories: ['Your score', 'Average', 'Highest Score']
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        borderColor: '#000000',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        colorByPoint: true
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                yAxis: {
                    max: 1900,
                    tickInterval: 100,
                    title: 'test'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Score',
                    data: [val1, 1450, 1900]
                }]
            };
        } else {
            $("#result").append("<div>Score must be between 0-1900</div>");
        }
        $('#container').highcharts(options);
}
```